# Scroll (left/right) with Magic Mouse (apple)

Tags: magic-mouse

I have an iMac with Ubuntu, as well as its wireless devices (Mouse, keyboard) however something has me very annoying and it is that the Scroll of the MagicMouse (wireless mouse of mac) also operates in the left and right section.

How to deactivate the scroll of those areas and that only works in the center?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with using the terminal, there's a *relatively* simple way to deactivate buttons using `xinput` (it works for disabling clicking the middle button as well). If xinput isn't installed on your computer, just open a terminal and use `sudo apt-get install xinput`.

Here are the steps to permanently disable the left and right scroll:

1. In any directory, use the `xinput` command. This should bring up a list of connected devices--here's an example of mine:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:02 04F3:304B Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:02 04F3:304B Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M705                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Google Pixel USB-C earbuds                id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Now, for my computer it listed a generic Mouse `MSFT0001:02 04F3:304B Mouse` in addition to the mouse I had actually plugged in (the `Logitech M705`). If you're unsure which mouse is yours, try unplugging it, running the command in the terminal again, and looking for the missing device.

2. Take the ID of your mouse (my Logitech mouse has id=9) and use the following command to get more information on the types of inputs recognized by the computer: 
   `xinput list <mouse-id-here>`

This should print up something similar to the following:

```
Logitech M705                               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 20
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" 
            "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" 
            "Button Horiz Wheel Right" "Button Side" "Button Extra" "Button Forward" 
            "Button Back" None None None None None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 9. Type: XIValuatorClass
        ... (more here)
```

The important part for you to notice here are the button labels listed. Look through the labels and find `"Button Horiz Wheel Left"` and `"Button Horiz Wheel Right"`. Figure out their position (mine are 6th and 7th in the list).

3. Now that you have those two positions, use the following command:

`xinput get-button-map <mouse-id-here>`

This should show you a list of numbers, like 1 through 20 for me:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Copy that list (if you're in a terminal you can do this with `ctrl-shift-C`, or `command-shift-C` for mac). Now use `xinput set-button-map <mouse-id-here> <list-of-numbers>`, pasting in the numbers and replacing the two that represent left scrolling and right scrolling with zeroes. So, for me it looks like:

```
xinput set-button-map <mouse-id-here> 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

This should make it so that your mouse no longer scrolls left and right.

4. If you don't want to have to do this every time you start up your computer, just open Startup Application Preferences (it should show up if you search for it in Ubuntu), click 'Add' and paste the full set-button-map command  in the `command` field. Now it should automatically run this command whenever your computer starts up. No guarantees that it will work if you disconnect and reconnect your mouse, though--you might have to restart your computer with the mouse plugged in for the change to take effect.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: I learned today that the device ID's can be subject to change between boots. This makes things a bit more difficult, but not unbearable.

Basically you'll need to use this command to pull out the ID number from xinput:

```
xinput | grep <device-name> | awk -F'[= \t]+' '{print $7}'
```

Note that that '7' might be a different number for you--just iterate through trying different numbers until it returns you the ID of your mouse. Then, enter the following command into the startup file:

```
xinput set-button-map "$(xinput | grep <device-name> | awk -F'[= \t]+' '{print $7}')" 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Once again, make sure the '7' is replaced by the number that works for you. I understand this answer has thoroughly spiraled out of relative ease and downward into grep/regex/awk oblivion, but hey, *it worked for me* :).

Good luck!